# how to detect discard button is pressed when sending email android

Tags: android

how to detect discard button is pressed when sending email android

Answer (score 2):

Write your own email client. Then, do whatever you want when the user discards an email in your own email client.

If you are expecting to find out when the user discards an email from any of the existing email clients, that is not possible, sorry.

Comment: is there any solutions for this